# How to set a file_upload control for a field in rails_admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm new to rails and I recently discovered rails_admin.

How to set a file_upload control for a field in rails_admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the [Carrierwave gem](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) for your file uploads you can do something like this
https://gist.github.com/884835 or in erb if you prefer that:

```
<%= label_tag "#{field.abstract_model.to_param}_#{field.name}", field.label %>
<div class="input">
<% image = field.bindings[:object].send(field.name) %>
<% if image.path %>
    <div class="row">
        <% default_version = image.versions[:main] %>
        <%= image_tag default_version && default_version.url || image.url %>
        <br />
        <%= form.check_box "remove_#{field.name}" %>
        <%= form.label "remove_#{field.name}", "Remove existing #{field.label.downcase}", :class => "inline" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
<div class="row">
    <%= form.file_field field.name, :class => "fileUploadField #{field.has_errors? ? "errorField" : nil}" %>
    <%= form.hidden_field "#{field.name}_cache" %>
</div>
</div>
```